# How can you create a RabbitMQ MessageListener using a topic exchange with autodeclared queues?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, message-listener

I am using RabbitMQ in Java using the Spring AMQP. I am sending messages using an topic exchange.

I want to consume the messages using autodeclared queues with a specified routingKey and the only way I managed to achieve this was using a Thread, where I would wait for the deliveries (using consumer.nextDelivery()). Is there any other way to do this async?

Also Spring AMQP has a MessageListener interface that I can use only to listen to named Queues. Is there a way I can use the MessageListener to consume messages from autodeclared queues?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can use the MessageListener to consume messages from autodeclared queues?

Actually it is a feature by defult: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/htmlsingle/#automatic-declaration.

And it is the main cool feature of AMQP protocol - automatically declare MQ objects on demand.
This rule works as for queus as well for exchanges and binding between them.

So, for you it's just enough to specify the binding for your queue to that topic exchange and refer the queue name from the `<listener-container>` configuration.

On start up of your application all AMQP objects will be populated to the RabbitMQ broker via `RabbitAdmin` component, if they aren't present on the broker yet, of course.

Comment: I tried using the `<listener-container>`, but when I declare it in the XML i need to write the queue's name. 


The thing is that I want to use an auto-declared queue for each routing-key. Currently I am using this:


`String queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
channel.queueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, routingKey);`



I need to create the listener using the autodeclared queue as above.

Comment: You can get access to the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` bean from that code and use its `addQueueNames` for those `anonymous` queues.

Comment: Probably this way I will need another class to create the queues and add them to my `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, that will have implemented the `onMessage` logic. Right? Or is there a better way to add the anonymous queueNames? Also thank you very much for the answers. They are very useful!

Comment: If you need the separete listener for each anonymous queue, you should create `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` for each of them. However it will be easy to have only one `generic` listener, get messages from all those queue and further do some `routing` logic in the target message handler. If you create queues manually, it's only one way to handle them via listener - use `addQueueNames` at runtime.